# Split Date Column then group by Date and get MAX Values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, group-by, max

I am working on an attendance system, I want to get the MAX value of user login basis on date.

Following is a simple select query

```
SELECT * FROM  CHECKINOUT 
WHERE USERID = 244
ORDER BY CHECKTIME DESC
```

Result of above query

```
   USERID   CHECKTIME
244 2/12/20 14:56
244 2/12/20 12:04
244 2/12/20 12:04
244 2/12/20 12:04
244 2/12/20 12:04
244 2/12/20 12:03
244 2/12/20 12:03
244 2/12/20 12:03
244 2/12/20 12:03
244 2/12/20 11:00
244 2/11/20 15:04
244 2/11/20 14:17
244 2/11/20 11:00
244 2/11/20 10:59
244 2/11/20 10:59
244 2/11/20 10:58
244 2/11/20 10:57
244 2/11/20 10:57
244 2/11/20 10:57
244 2/10/20 14:50
244 2/10/20 13:58
244 2/7/20 15:39
244 2/7/20 9:18
```

I Split `CHECKTIME` column into Date and time

```
SELECT USERID, 
        ( CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CHECKTIME, 101) ) AS DATEPART,
        ( CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CHECKTIME, 108) ) AS TIMEPART    
FROM     CHECKINOUT 

WHERE USERID = 244
GROUP BY USERID, CHECKTIME
ORDER BY CHECKTIME DESC
```

Result

```
USERID  DATEPART    TIMEPART
244 2/12/2020   14:56:57
244 2/12/2020   12:04:32
244 2/12/2020   12:04:17
244 2/12/2020   12:04:13
244 2/12/2020   12:04:06
244 2/12/2020   12:03:40
244 2/12/2020   12:03:35
244 2/12/2020   12:03:28
244 2/12/2020   12:03:01
244 2/12/2020   11:00:23
244 2/11/2020   15:04:01
244 2/11/2020   14:17:57
244 2/11/2020   11:00:50
244 2/11/2020   10:59:29
244 2/11/2020   10:59:21
244 2/11/2020   10:58:10
244 2/11/2020   10:57:35
244 2/11/2020   10:57:33
244 2/11/2020   10:57:29
244 2/10/2020   14:50:19
244 2/10/2020   13:58:54
244 2/7/2020    15:39:44
244 2/7/2020    9:18:47
```

My Desire Out is

```
USERID  DATEPART    TIMEPART
244 2/12/2020   14:56:57
244 2/11/2020   15:04:01
244 2/10/2020   14:50:19
244 2/7/2020    15:39:44
244 2/6/2020    18:21:04
```

Now I want to get Maximum Time for each date. Can you guys help me?

Comment: What is your expected output? `MAX()` with `group by` not working? And what is your SQL SERVER version? Also Please do not post the sample data as an image but post it as a text.

Comment: @ArunPalanisamy I updated my question with my desired output. And SQL Server is 2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following

```
SELECT USERID,
       CAST(CHECKTIME AS DATE) DATEPART,
       MAX(CAST(CHECKTIME AS TIME)) as MAX_TIME
FROM CHECKINOUT
GROUP BY USERID,CAST(CHECKTIME AS DATE)
ORDER by CAST(CHECKTIME AS DATE) DESC
```

[**CHECK DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=17b467e2752809e65b1688b3eabb79b1)

OUTPUT

```
+--------+------------+----------+
| USERID | DATEPART   | MAX_TIME |
+--------+------------+----------+
| 244    | 2020-02-12 | 14:56:00 |
+--------+------------+----------+
| 244    | 2020-02-11 | 15:04:00 |
+--------+------------+----------+
| 244    | 2020-02-10 | 14:50:00 |
+--------+------------+----------+
| 244    | 2020-02-07 | 15:39:00 |
+--------+------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #temp
(USERID int,CHECKTIME datetime)


insert into #temp values (244 ,'2/12/20 14:56')
insert into #temp values (244 ,'2/12/20 12:04')
insert into #temp values (244 ,'2/12/20 12:04')
insert into #temp values (244 ,'2/12/20 12:04')
insert into #temp values (244 ,'2/12/20 12:04')
insert into #temp values (244 ,'2/12/20 12:03')
insert into #temp values (244 ,'2/12/20 12:03')
insert into #temp values (244 ,'2/12/20 12:03')
insert into #temp values (244 ,'2/12/20 12:03')
insert into #temp values (244 ,'2/12/20 11:00')
insert into #temp values (244 ,'2/11/20 15:04')
insert into #temp values (244 ,'2/11/20 14:17')
insert into #temp values (244 ,'2/11/20 11:00')
insert into #temp values (244 ,'2/11/20 10:59')
insert into #temp values (244 ,'2/11/20 10:59')
insert into #temp values (244 ,'2/11/20 10:58')
insert into #temp values (244 ,'2/11/20 10:57')
insert into #temp values (244 ,'2/11/20 10:57')
insert into #temp values (244 ,'2/11/20 10:57')
insert into #temp values (244 ,'2/10/20 14:50')
insert into #temp values (244 ,'2/10/20 13:58')
insert into #temp values (244 ,'2/7/20 15:39' )
insert into #temp values (244 ,'2/7/20 9:18'  )

    select USERID,[DATEPART],max(timepart)[timepart] from (
    SELECT USERID, 
         cast(CHECKTIME as date)  AS DATEPART,
         cast(CHECKTIME as time)  AS TIMEPART    
FROM     #temp 

WHERE USERID = 244
) as t
group by USERID,DATEPART
drop table #temp
```

Comment: I tried this but it giving the following error `Column "CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
`

Comment: And if I use MAX in Order by it giving only one record

Answer (score 0):

```
select USERID,
       cast(checktime as date) DATEPART,
      MAX(cast(checktime as time)) as TIMEPART
from checkinout
group BY userid,cast(checktime as date)
order by cast(checktime as date) desc
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for answering. While this code might answer the question, can you consider adding some explanation for what the problem was you solved, and how you solved it? This will help future readers to understand your answer better and learn from it.